# How to stop Vagrant automatically when closing PhpStorm

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm

When I'm ready to go home, I close PhpStorm, forgetting to halt Vagrant first.
Only to notice the day after my Vagrant is corrupted.
Why can't PhpStorm give me notice it's still there (hey - usability!).

So, is there a way to tell PhpStorm to check this and give me a notice I shouldn't quit PhpStorm without halting the Vagrant? Or auto-halt the Vagrant himself?

Comment: Nice idea to get a reminder like 'Vagrant still running!'. But you should also look into your vagrant, mine is never corrupt when I close phpStorm, Macbook and leave work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality ATM.

So far I have found these tickets/comments:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10632#comment=27-1214057 (similar idea)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11227 (similar idea -- execute `vagrant suspend` on project close)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12334 (execute certain tasks on project open/close)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5622 (project open/close events)

Previous requests that asked the same (marked as duplicate of the above tickets):

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22473